# Permission denied for root shrc

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command, centos

Whenever I open the terminal on my Centos5.1, I always get this error

```
/root/.cshrc Permission denied
```

and then I can't use networking commands (ip,ifconfig,...) because they are reported as unknown commands.

Comment: are you logged in as root? what is the file mode? Can you show output of command ls -l /root/.cshrc ?

Comment: You are getting "unknown command" because the PATH (or, in csh, path) variable is not set.  Call the commands using the full heirarchic name, for example /sbin/ifconfig (or whereever it is on your system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you have permissions to read .cshrc To do that issue:

ls -l /root/.cshrc

If the output begins with to dashes it means that you don't. To give yourself read permission to this file issue:

chmod +r /root/.cshrc

Now if you run `ls -l /root/.cshrc` the output should start with `-r`.

Comment: Funny, I'm getting the same error even though I technically have "r" permissions.  Even logging in with root.  Something's broken...